# Using XML Bulk Load to Import large XML data into SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, vbscript

I've downloaded the latest English Wikipedia dump ([enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download)), and I'm trying to import it to SQL server 2012 by using  XML Bulk Load. This is the VBScript code I've used:

```
Dim objBL 
Set objBL = CreateObject("SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkload.4.0")
objBL.ConnectionString = "provider=SQLOLEDB;datasource=localhost;
database=Wikipedia;integrated security=SSPI"
objBL.ErrorLogFile = "error.log"

objBL.CheckConstraints=true
objBL.XMLFragment = True
objBL.SchemaGen = True
objBL.SGDropTables = True

objBL.Execute "export-0.8.xml", "enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml"
Set objBL = Nothing
```

This VBScript should generate the tables and load the Wikipedia XML file into them. The VBScript code also uses the [wikimedia XSD schema](http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8.xsd). However, I'm getting this error:

```
 schema multiple base for a derived type on lang is not supported
 code: 80004005
```

Any help with this problem would be appropriate!

Comment: Seems there is a problem with the "lang" column in your schema.